# Injecting reverse proxy HTTP headers into Express.js app

Tags: apache, express, http-headers, relative-path, reverse-proxy

My Express.js app uses absolute paths (e.g., `/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`, etc.) When I reverse proxy this, in Apache, at the domain root, it works fine. However, if I RP it at any different path, the app's paths don't resolve. For example, if I RP at `/app` then the app will attempt to fetch `/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`, whereas it *should* be fetching `/app/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`, etc.

As an attempt to resolve this, I have my Apache configuration setting the `X-Script-Name` header to `/app`:

```
Header add "X-Script-Name" /app
```

I hope to then inject this into the frontend code as it's served by Express. For example, instead of:

```
<script src='/assets/something.js'></script>
```

...we would have something akin to:

```
<script src='${X-Script-Name}/assets/something.js'></script>
```

The problem I'm having is getting the `X-Script-Name` value in Express. I had assumed it would be in the router's `req.headers`, but this is just the headers being pushed through by Express... How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a plain `Header` will set a response header.

You need to add a request header so your downstream app can access it, therefore you need to use the [RequestHeader](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive like so:

`RequestHeader set X-Script-Name "/app"`